# How to write dictionary with huge data to csv files using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a huge amount of data from a dict to csv file, but the writing stops after about a million lines of data. Following is the code:

```
import os
from nltk import ngrams

with open('four_grams.csv', 'w') as f:
for i in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\rocki\Downloads\Compressed\train'):
    if i.endswith('.bytes'):
        with open(i) as file:
            content=file.read()
            new_content = ' '.join([w for w in content.split() if len(w)<3])
            four_grams=ngrams(new_content.split(), 4)
            grams_dict={}
            for grams in four_grams:
                gram=' '.join(grams)
                if gram not in grams_dict:
                    grams_dict[gram]=1
                else:
                    grams_dict[gram]=grams_dict[gram]+1                    
                for key in grams_dict.keys():
                    f.write("%s,%s\n"%(key,grams_dict[key]))
```

Any suggestion as to how to achieve this?

Comment: add `a` in option of `open('four_grams.csv', 'wa')`. That allows you to  write one line at a time, without creating the whole dictionary.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide for your question: a) IN: sample dict data , b) OUT: format of desired csv-file

Comment: When you say "the writing stops", is there an error message?

Comment: What do you mean by 'stops'? How did you determine how many lines have been written, and that writing stopped?

Comment: @JoeP It stops, meaning when I open it, it says file not loaded completely

Comment: @QuangHoang I am searching for existing keys as well, and I heard dictionaries' search time is better. I am open to any suggestions as to how do I write without dictionary as well.

Comment: @UzairRiaz "it says file not loaded completely" - what is "it"? Your program or the operating system? How big is the file? What is the *exact* error message? Maybe the csv is being created correctly, but is too large to be loaded into memory by any tool.

Comment: @JoeP when opening the csv file in excel, it says file not loaded completely. I am trying to write multiple files' output in csv file and I know one of them has more than 70k lines. So I am pretty sure that their combination would go well over a few millionn lines, but only a million can be written and the program stops succesfully with no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, it wasn't the program that was not writing successfully but the excel file that could not load such huge data completely. Used delimit trial to check that the data was written exactly as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to want to use [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to write the csv. This code assumes that each `grams_dict` is structured the same. I haven't had pandas choke on a large csv write yet. Hopefully it will run alright for you!

```
import pandas as pd

saved_dfs = [] # Create an empty list where we will save each new dataframe (grams_dict) created.

for i in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\rocki\Downloads\Compressed\train'):
    if i.endswith('.bytes'):
        with open(i) as file:
            content=file.read()
            new_content = ' '.join([w for w in content.split() if len(w)<3])
            four_grams=ngrams(new_content.split(), 4)
            grams_dict={}
            for grams in four_grams:
                gram=' '.join(grams)
                if gram not in grams_dict:
                    grams_dict[gram]=1
                else:
                    grams_dict[gram]=grams_dict[gram]+1
            df = pd.DataFrame(data=grams_dict) # create a new DataFrame for each file opened
            saved_dfs.append(df)

final_grams_dict = pd.concat(saved_dfs) # Combine all of the saved grams_dict's into one DataFrame Object

final_grams_dict.to_csv('path.csv')
```

Good Luck!

Comment: still caps after a million lines, even though the programs ends succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you know where the code chokes (or file-viewer)? You are talking about millions of rows, your code could very well choke on the lists from `.split()`. Lists are notoriously slow when growing large. Without any hints of your actual data there is no way of knowing.

Anyways, here is a version that limits the size of the lists. To make it a runnable example your actual io is replaced with some fake lines.

```
import os
from nltk import ngrams
from io import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

string_file = """
1 2 3 a b c ab cd ef
4 5 6 g h i gh ij kl
abcde fghijkl
"""

read_lines = 2 # choose something that does not make too long lists for .split()
csvf = StringIO()
#with open('four_grams.csv', 'wb') as csvf:
if True: # just for indention from with...
#    for i in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\rocki\Downloads\Compressed\train'):
    for i in range(1): # for the indention
#        if i.endswith('.bytes'):
#            with open(i) as bfile:
                bfile = StringIO(string_file)
                # get hold of line count
                chunks = bfile.read().count('\n') // read_lines
                bfile.seek(0)
                memory_line = ''
                grams_dict = defaultdict(int)
                for j in range(chunks):
                    tmp = bfile.readlines(read_lines)
                    content = ' '.join([memory_line] + tmp)
                    memory_line = tmp[-1]
                    new_content = ' '.join([w for w in content.split() if len(w)<3])
                    four_grams = ngrams(new_content.split(), 4)
                    for grams in four_grams:
                        #print(grams, len(grams_dict))
                        gram=' '.join(grams)
                        grams_dict[gram] += 1
                for k, v in grams_dict.items():
                    # assuming that it's enough to write the dict
                    # when it's filled rather than duplicating info
                    # in the resulting csv
                    csvf.write("%s\t%s\n"%(k, v))
                csvf.flush() # writes buffer if anything there
#print(grams_dict)
```

If it truly is your dict that is too large, you should divide that one as well. One way of doing that would be to make a 2 level dict and use `string.ascii_letters` as first key, and as 2nd level you put the grams_dict only holding keys that start with the respective single character.

At last, the use of `memory_line` could be skipped, when it's there it will do duplicate counts for whatever is in there, but if your `read_lines` is a fairly large number I would not bother about that.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're writing each line at a time. 
That can cause an I/O problem.

Try writing number of lines each time instead of one line at a time. Try writing 2 lines each time and add a line if it stops.

Comment: That's what file buffers are for. Python file objects come with a buffer attached, and the OS also uses buffering.